# SQL Server query excude all null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to form a query that would allow me to count **only** the rows that are not **NULL**

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM jSettings 
WHERE linkToJData = '56211010105' 
  AND tblName1 IS NOT NULL 
  AND tblName2 IS NOT NULL;
```

I have columns called `tblName1` - `tblName25`.

All I am looking to accomplish is to find out how many `tblNameXX` there are `without` a `NULL`.

The query above only produces a `1` every time.

Comment: And how many rows with `linkToJData = '56211010105'` are there?

Comment: Columns called `tblName1`, `tblName2`, `tblName3` etc. - not very intuitive... you just basically need to extend your `WHERE` clause to check **every single column** for `IS NOT NULL`...

Comment: so are tblName1 - tblName25 columns in the table?

Comment: I just tested this in SQLFiddle, and the query does what it's supposed to.  Could you provide a snapshot of some of your table data?

Comment: If you have 25 columns in your table that are nullable, you have a serious design issue.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Just one table

Comment: @Don Yes, they are columns.

Comment: @RandyMinder Not that i wanted to do it that way but the way i populate the row is seeing how many **custom fields** are in a report i download. I never know how many tables are going to be used for each linkToJData. One may just have name, address and email while another may just have email. tblName1 would hold the value **name**, tblName2 would hold **address** and tblName3 would hold **email**. Etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
 sum(case when tblName1 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName2 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName3 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName4 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName5 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName6 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName7 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName8 is null then 0 else 1 end)   
FROM jSettings 
WHERE linkToJotData = '56211010105'
```

This does report **7** which would be correct since the only table that has *NULL* is tblName8.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
 sum(case when tblName1 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName2 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName3 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName4 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName5 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName6 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName7 is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 sum(case when tblName8 is null then 0 else 1 end)   
FROM jSettings 
WHERE linkToJotData = '56211010105'
```

No need to union multiple result sets. This technique only requires a single pass over the data.

Comment: Ah that does work but how would i be able to sum ALL those up into only one calculated digit?

Comment: Just like you would sum any set of numbers: Place a `+` between them :) (Sum the aggregates by replacing the comma with a plus).

Comment: You have to remove the "as xxx" part.

Comment: I edited it manually because your edit was rejected by others in the meantime. I was unable to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the AND condition. If you provide AND condition you will get only those records where all the values for TBLNAME1..25 is populated.
But your requirement is to find individually how many records are having not null value.

you can use union for each columns and get the count separately and them sum up them to get the total count of not null values.

Let me know if this is what is intended.

Comment: Yes, thats what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're looking for records where both tblName1 and tblName2 are null. Is that your intention? If it's not, then you could try:

```
Select count(*) totalrows 
From jSettings 
where linkToJData = '56211010105' 
  and (tblName1 IS NOT NULL OR tblName2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: @Ajith Sasidharan worded it correctly for what i am looking to do.

Comment: Your query produces a **1** which would be incorrect since both tblName1 and tblName2 are not null... unless it starts at **0**?

Comment: ok, didn't know exactly what you needed, but i'm glad you make it!, regards

Answer (score 0):

you can do follows

```
declare @Data xml = 
(
    select *
    from jSettings
    where linkToJData = '56211010105'
    for xml path('row')
)

select count(*)
from @Data.nodes('/row/*[local-name(.) != "linkToJData"]') as T(C);
```

if you don't want to use xml, you can use this query:

```
select count(*)
from jSettings as j
    outer apply (values
        (j.tblName1),
        (j.tblName2),
        (j.tblName3),
        (j.tblName4),
        (j.tblName5)
    ) as C(name)
where j.linkToJData = '56211010105' and c.name is not null;
```

If you have many columns ans don't want to specify it manually:

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt =
    isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + '(j.' + c.name + ')'
from sys.syscolumns as c
where id = object_id('dbo.jSettings') and c.name <> 'linkToJData'

select @stmt = '
select count(*)
from jSettings as j
    outer apply (values ' + @stmt + ') as C(name)
where j.linkToJData = @linkToJData and c.name is not null'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt,
    @params = N'@linkToJData nvarchar(128)',
    @linkToJData = '56211010105'
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51178/7)</kbd>**

I suggest 1st or 3rd one - so you don't have to change your query for new columns

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 'tblName1',count(*) totalrows1 
From jSettings 
where linkToJData = '56211010105' 
  and tblName1 IS NOT NULL
union
Select 'tblName2',count(*) totalrows2
From jSettings 
where linkToJData = '56211010105' 
  and tblName2 IS NOT NULL
```

Try this code to get individual counts.